# Remove/Change list highlight-color (or adjust space between items)

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am currently making a custom row template for a SwiftUI-list for a **MacOS**-application. Since i didn't find a way remove/adjust the blue highlight-color (I only found solutions for iOS), I made the the following template which covers the blue-part but "mimics" it within the desired area, which looks like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awngP.png). I managed to cover most of the highlight-color by using negative paddings, etc.; however, I just can't get rid of some blue pixels on the top of the item (marked in screenshot).

My code looks like this:

**Row template (simplified version)**

```
struct EntryRow: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        // Outer frame (white space with shadow)
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            
            // Inner frame (actual content)
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {

                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(.vertical, 0)
            .background(self.model.selectedEntries.firstIndex(of: entry.id) != nil ? Color.blue : Color(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor))
 //  Changes color according to selection state of row
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 0)
            )
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
            
            
        }.padding(15)
            .background(Color(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor))
 //  Changes background color so that it corresponds to the list's background color (which achieves the white space between the items)
            .shadow(color: Color(NSColor.tertiaryLabelColor), radius: 2)
        
    }    
}
```

**List**

The rows are loaded as follows:

```
List(selection: self.$model.selectedEntries) {
                    ForEach(self.model.entries, id: \.id) { item in
                        EntryRow(entry: item)
                            .padding(-15)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .padding(.top, -13).padding(.horizontal, -4)
```

**Question**

**Is there a way to cover the remaining highlight color, or - even better - to remove the highlight color entirely?** Unfortunately, adjusting the paddings further doesn't seem to help... (but maybe I'm missing something)

Thanks a lot in advance.

***Update***

The selection binding looks as follows (in case that is relevant:

```
    class UserDataViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var entries = [Entry]()
    
    @Published var selectedEntries: Set<Int32> = Set<Int32>() {
        didSet {
            print(selectedEntries.count)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose the change a direction... If you don't want default selection (the highlight you fight with) then just don't use it and make it just on tap, like in below example (due to provided snapshot is not testable)

Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
struct PersonList: View {
    @State var selectedPerson: String?

    let persons = ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selected: \(selectedPerson ?? "<none>")")
            List {
                 ForEach(persons, id: \.self) { person in
                    VStack {
                        Text(person)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedPerson = person
                    }
                 }
                 .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternate:** here is possible alternate based on `NSTableView` (which is underneath of `List` on macOS) notifications

```
List(selection: self.$model.selectedEntries) {
    ForEach(self.model.entries, id: \.id) { item in
        EntryRow(entry: item)
    }
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSTableView.selectionIsChangingNotification)) { notification in
    if let tableView = notification.object as? NSTableView {
        tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift reply! I have tried implementing your code but didn't manage to get multi-select to work (I have added just added to code for the selection binding - please let me know, if I should add further code). How could I implement this? Btw, would the selection work as usual (with keyboard, etc.) when implementing a tap gesture? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been searching for this literally for days! Besides, it's simply epic the amount of useful advice you are giving here.. Now it looks like this: https://ibb.co/v4kLzBK : )

Comment: @Asperi, works well with an odd bug I'll try to sort. In a three-pane view, the first click to select a middle pane item wipes out (i.e., turns blank) the middle/right panes, even though the left most pane's item is still selected. Any subsequent clicks will perform without problem. Any tip on what I should look at while troubleshooting this?